# How to pass Headers using HTTP component in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

Hi I am working with Any Point Studio and i want to pass headers with the current request with a key value pair How to achieve that using existing HTTP Component.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke the HTTP Inbound through Mule Client, here is an example:

```
MuleClient muleClient = new MuleClient(muleContext);
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
headers.put("key", "456453N123");
MuleMessage result = muleClient.send("http://localhost:8081/prm", PAYLOAD, headers);
```

The HTTP headers are in the inbound-scoped properties of the MuleMessage. To get the header from a flow, you can use:

```
<logger level="INFO" message="Header Content-Type = #[header:key]"/>
```

Comment: cant we use directly using this HTTP component

Comment: I do not understand your concern, could describe it in more detail?

Comment: instead of using mule client is their any way i can configure in Http component itself to pass the headers directly

Comment: The HTTP header automatically stored in inbound message properties. You can use <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
   <add-message-property key="Accept" value="application/json"/>
</message-properties-transformer> for a http:outbound-endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You can also set header using the Property component or Message properties for setting multiple header data see below: