# Basic flow results in NullPayload

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I'm new to Mule and I'm trying to get the very first example from the book "Mule in Action" working.

I'm using Mule 3.9 and Anypoint Studio 6.4.1.  In chapter 1 they describe a very basic product_registration flow that I have created as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8880" basePath="products" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" username="admin" password="admin" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
    <flow name="product_registrationFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger Before"/>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger After"/>
        <jms:outbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" queue="products"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

and an accompanying functional test:

```
@Test
public void testCanRegisterProducts() throws Exception {

    LocalMuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();

    String productAsJson = "{ \"name\":\"Widget\", \"price\": 9.99, \"weight\": 1.0, \"sku\": \"abcd-56789\" }";

    MuleMessage source = new DefaultMuleMessage(productAsJson, muleContext);
    client.dispatch("http://localhost:8880/products", source);

    MuleMessage result = client.request("jms://products", RECEIVE_TIMEOUT);

    assertNotNull(result);
    assertFalse(result.getPayload() instanceof NullPayload);
    assertEquals(productAsJson, result.getPayloadAsString());
}
```

When I run the test it fails at the last assert because the actual payload is:

```
{NullPayload}
```

And if I look directly in ActiveMQ I see that payload. If I manually post to Mule (using a tool like Poster in Chrome, setting only the header Content-Type: application/json) the payload is valid JSON and I can get the test to pass (because it is getting the pending message from the queue posted by Poster and the message it creates is at the end of the queue with payload {NullPayload}.

Can someone shed some light on why the flow fails when invoked from the JUnit test, but seems to work when invoked by using a tool like Poster?

Update: With the help of Pierre B. I got it working.  The initialization of the MuleMessage in the FunctionalTestCase was updated as follows:

```
    MuleMessage source = new DefaultMuleMessage(productAsJson, muleContext);
    source.setProperty("Content-Type", "application/json", PropertyScope.INBOUND);
    source.setProperty("Content-Length", Integer.valueOf(productAsJson.length()), PropertyScope.INBOUND);
```

Comment: "And if I look directly in ActiveMQ I see that payload" You mean that after your test ran in JUnit you see the NullPayload in ActiveMQ, or you see your JSON content? "because it is getting the pending message from the queue posted by Poster and the message it creates is at the end of the queue with payload {NullPayload}" You mean you first posted a message with Poster, then ran the test, it passes but the NullPayload message remains in the queue?

Comment: Yes, if I look in ActiveMQ (using the ActiveMQ admin console) the payload of the messages created with the test case are literally "{NullPayload}", but if I run Mule and use Poster to send the same JSON to the same HTTP inbound endpoint, the JSON shows up correctly in ActiveMQ admin console.  You are also correct in your understanding of how I can get the test to "pass" - the queue becomes out of sequence and the test posts a msg with {NullPayload}, and then reads a msg previous posted with Poster and passes - the msg from the test remains in the queue.

Comment: Ok so this is probably caused by the way you generate the message using your MuleClient, it is probably not recognized properly by Mule. What is your log before/after output? If nothing is given configure your loggers to output the current message or payload with `message="#[message]"`or `message="#[payload]"`

Comment: Thanks @PierreB.  I will give this a try and report back - I agree with your logic and I tried debugging - I see the correct payload and originalPayload immediately after construction but I wasn't able to spend enough time to understand what happened in the dispatch call.  I'm suspecting it has to do with Mule not knowing the MuleMessage contains JSON?

Comment: Exactly my thought, I just added an answer regarding this. You may need to specifiy the content type with your MuleMessage dispath call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it works when you POST a message using an external tool instead of MuleClient:

> using a tool like Poster in Chrome, setting only the header Content-Type: application/json

Try adding the same header to your `MuleMessage` such as:

```
MuleMessage source = new DefaultMuleMessage(productAsJson, muleContext);

# define the headers
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers.put("Content-Length", sourceLength);

# add the headers as function parameter
client.dispatch("http://localhost:8880/products", source, headers);
```

EDIT: as @sceaj pointed out, both Content-Type and Content-Length headers are required.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27149882/how-to-pass-headers-using-http-component-in-mule for details on how to pass headers

Comment: I just tried this and unfortunately it fails saying the actual JMS message contents are still {[NullPayload]}.  I will try the logging later today and update.

Comment: Comparing the output from the logging, I still needed to add "Content-Length" header (in addition to Content-Type). If you update your answer @PierreB I'll accept it.

Comment: Great to see that works ;) I edited as you proposed, thanks